# c++ making random engine static

Tags: c++, random

Im trying to make the random engine for my random helper class:

Its workign when im using this code:

Helper.h

```
#pragma once
class Helper
{
public:
    static int getRandomInt(int min, int max);
    static double getRandomDouble(double min, double max);
};
```

Helper.cpp

```
#include <random>
int Helper::getRandomInt(int min, int max)
{
    static std::default_random_engine randomEngine{};
    using Dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>;
    static Dist uid{};
    return uid(randomEngine, Dist::param_type{ min,max});
}

double Helper::getRandomDouble(double min, double max)
{
    static std::default_random_engine randomEngine{};
    using Dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>;
    static Dist uid{};
    return uid(randomEngine, Dist::param_type{ min,max });
}
```

So I thought why not use the same random engine and tried:

Helper.h added:

```
static std::default_random_engine randomEngine;
```

helper.cpp changed:

```
//added randomEngine
std::default_random_engine Helper::randomEngine = std::default_random_engine{};

int Helper::getRandomInt(int min, int max)
{
    //removed randomeEngine 
    using Dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>;
    static Dist uid{};
    return uid(randomEngine, Dist::param_type{ min,max});
}

double Helper::getRandomDouble(double min, double max)
{
    //removed randomeEngine 
    using Dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>;
    static Dist uid{};
    return uid(randomEngine, Dist::param_type{ min,max });
}
```

When I try to run it I get 10 errors:

default_random_engine': is not a member of 'std'

missing type specifier - int assumed

When I add an static int (just to test) like:

Helper.h

```
static int test;
```

Helper.cpp

```
int Helper::test = 3;
```

There are no compile errors, what is the difference between creating a static random engine and a static int?

Note: The first example is working and I have included  (else the first example would not work)

Comment: `#include <random>`?

Comment: You need to include the appropriate headers. C++ will not find all std:: symbols by default.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean  I have included the headers, note the first example is working.

Comment: @SvenB: you need to include `<random>` in `Helper.h`, not `Helper.cpp`.

Comment: (a) What is the point of public constructor/destructor when all methods are static? (b) `static std::default_random_engine randomEngine;` does not belong in your header file, only in cpp file. If you declare it in the header file, every cpp file that includes the header gets its own copy (which is never used),

Comment: @Arkadiy If i dont declare randomEngine in the header I wont be able to create one in the cpp file because Helper wont have a member randomEngine. Agree on the constructor destructor though.

Comment: There is no need for "<random>" and "randomEngine" in your Helper.h. Your "randomEngine" can be initialized in cpp file simply by doing "static std::default_random_engine randomEngine = std::default_random_engine{};" instead of "std::default_random_engine Helper::randomEngine = std::default_random_engine{};"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors suggest that you're forgetting to include the `<random>` header in `Helper.h`.

Changing `Helper.h` to:

```
#pragma once
#include <random>

class Helper
{
    static std::default_random_engine randomEngine;

public:
    Helper();
    ~Helper();
    static int getRandomInt(int min, int max);
    static double getRandomDouble(double min, double max);
};
```

...should fix your issue.

Comment: Your right, i totally forgot i needed to move the include.

Comment: @SvenB: you're welcome. Don't forget to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it answered your question.